# Looking for guidance on creating a screen sharing Android app for Raspberry Pi with a smaller display

Tags: java, android, android-studio, raspberry-pi4, screensharing

How can I make an android app that shares the whole screen of my android phone to my raspberry pi4 screen with 3.5 inch display? is there any tutorial or something that you can recommend?

I tried genymobile scrcpy but I wanted to do something myself but something like scrcpy too but im noob.. haha

Comment: You should take a look at MediaProjection and MediaEncoder APIs. At the end it will be like a video streaming problem.